# IDP initiated SSO for Spring SAML Extension

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, spring-saml

I have impleneted SSO solution using Spring SAML extension now i would like test IDP initiated SSO

Could any one please give me the URL for IDP initiated SSO  for Spring SAML Extension with respect to idp.ssocircle.com

Answer (score 1):

Use the following URL and replace spEntityID with your own unique identifier:

https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/saml2/jsp/idpSSOInit.jsp?metaAlias=/ssocircle&spEntityID=saml-federation.appspot.com

Comment: Thanks for the quick information.I again hit a road block as we do have 2 resources/URL under SSO implementation if we are initiating SSO from IDP how do we differentiate between these.

Please help

Comment: Documentation for the idpSSOInit.jsp is here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19854-01/819-5209/gbtkd/index.html, you can use RelayState and consume it in Spring SAML by changing successRedirectHandler to "org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler"